# Error with custom gn-menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, web

I'm building new website testing gn-menu by google. I tried a custom ui of this google menu.

I can't understand why is the jquery defined `#gn-menu` as:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function.

```
    ! function(a) {
    "use strict";

    function b() {
        var b = !1;
        return function(a) {
            (/(android|ipad|playbook|silk|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) && (b = !0)
        }(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || a.opera), b
    }

    function c(a, b) {
        this.el = a, this._init()
    }
    c.prototype = {
        _init: function() {
            this.trigger = this.el.querySelector("#menu-btn"), this.menu = this.el.querySelector("nav.gn-menu-wrapper"), this.hotArea = this.el.querySelector("ul.gn-menu"), this.isMenuOpen = !1, this.eventtype = b() ? "touchstart" : "click", this._initEvents();
            var a = this;
            this.bodyClickFn = function() {
                a._closeMenu(), $(this).off(a.eventtype, a.bodyClickFn)
            }
        },
        _initEvents: function() {
            var a = this,
                c = $(this.trigger),
                d = $(document),
                e = $(this.menu);
            b() || (c.on("mouseover", function(b) {
                a._openIconMenu()
            }), c.on("mouseout", function(b) {
                a._closeIconMenu()
            }), e.on("mouseout", function(b) {
                a._closeMenu()
            }), $(this.hotArea).on("mouseover", function(b) {
                a._openMenu(), d.on(a.eventtype, a.bodyClickFn)
            })), c.on(this.eventtype, function(b) {
                b.stopPropagation(), b.preventDefault(), a.isMenuOpen ? (a._closeMenu(), d.off(a.eventtype, a.bodyClickFn)) : (a._openMenu(), d.off(a.eventtype, a.bodyClickFn))
            }), e.on(this.eventtype, function(a) {
                a.stopPropagation()
            })
        },
        _openIconMenu: function() {
            classie.add(this.menu, "gn-open-part")
        },
        _closeIconMenu: function() {
            classie.remove(this.menu, "gn-open-part")
        },
        _openMenu: function() {
            this.isMenuOpen || (classie.add(this.trigger, "gn-selected"), this.isMenuOpen = !0, classie.add(this.menu, "gn-open-all"), this._closeIconMenu())
        },
        _closeMenu: function() {
            this.isMenuOpen && (classie.remove(this.trigger, "gn-selected"), this.isMenuOpen = !1, classie.remove(this.menu, "gn-open-all"), this._closeIconMenu())
        }
    }, a.gnMenu = c
}(window);
```

I'm getting problem with `c = $(this.trigger),` as:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul id="gn-menu" class="gn-menu-main">
    <span class='mtitle'>{$title}</span>
                            <li class="gn-trigger" id="menu-btn">
                    <a class="gn-icon gn-icon-menu"></a>
                    <nav class="gn-menu-wrapper">
                        <div class="gn-scroller">
                            <ul class="gn-menu">
                                <li><a href="/main" class="gn-icon"><i class="nav-icon lnr lnr-home"></i> דף הבית</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/profile" class="gn-icon"><i class="nav-icon lnr lnr-paperclip"></i> פרופיל חברה</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/gall" class="gn-icon"><i class="nav-icon lnr lnr-picture"></i> תיק עבודות</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/articles" class="gn-icon"><i class="nav-icon lnr lnr-book"></i> מאמרים</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/faqs" class="gn-icon"><i class="nav-icon lnr lnr-question-circle"></i> עזרה ראשונה</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{$row['store']}" class="gn-icon"><i class="nav-icon lnr lnr-store"></i> חנות</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/contact" class="gn-icon"><i class="nav-icon lnr lnr-envelope"></i> צור קשר</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!-- /gn-scroller -->
                    </nav>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

I really need a hand here.

Comment: Probably related to the fact that you are not including jquery properly or some other libraries are shadowing the $ function (actually alias). Some more infos about jquery conflicts here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  c = $(this.trigger)
});
```

More info: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/